# Should bean validation be performed on entities or controller DTOs?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, javabeans

i have an application that manages orders. I have a controller that receives an OrderDTO to create it, and the entity Order, which is created and passed to OrderService to save it

I want to validate that this order has some properties, and I am wondering, where should i use the javax bean validation annotations? Should they be at the controller level, or inside OrderService ?

I am using play framework by the way

Comment: If you use Spring answer is in another special component with using Validation Valid see more here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such simple bean validations are defined in DTO classes at the controller layer to be executed upon the API request to ensure the request is valid before calling the service layer. Check `play.data.validation.Validation`

On the other hand, the entities may have bean validations according to the database constraints and must be completely isolated from the controller layer.

Comment: Would the validation of the dto, and the entity, have any difference? My dto is essentially just a copy of the entity. I could use it directly anyway. For example i have a validation that says no other order with the same code must exist in the db. Would that be on the dto? Thanks

Comment: The validation "no other order with the same code must exist in the DB" is for sure a database validation and must take place in the service layer. You must define a unique constrain in the database table in the column "code" to ensure no duplicate orders have the same code. Also, query the database in the service layer, and if you find an order with the same code, don't insert the new one.